# PCRE regex backreference works, but subroutines do not

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to match the texts:

**1.** "HeyHey HeyHey"

**2.** "HeyHey HeyHeyy"

with the regexes:

**a** `/(\w+) \1\w/`

**b** `/(\w+) (\w+)\w/`

**c** `/(\w+) (?1)\w/`

---

- Regex ***a*** matches ***1*** completely, and ***2*** completely but the last 'y'.
- Regex ***b*** completely matches ***1*** and ***2***.
- Regex ***c*** does not match ***1*** or ***2***.

Following http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines I thought b and c are equivalent. But apparently, they are not.

What is the difference? Why is the subroutine not working, while copying the same regex works?

experimented here: https://regex101.com/#pcre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because with PCRE, the reference to a subpattern *(`(?1)` here)* is atomic by default.

*(Note that this behaviour is particular to PCRE and Perl doesn't share it.)*

The subpattern is `\w+` *(with a greedy quantifier)*, all the word characters are matched *(`HeyHeyy` in the second string)*, but since `(?1)` is atomic, the regex engine can't backtrack and give back the last `y` to make `\w` succeed.

You can obtain the same result with this pattern:

```
/(\w+) (?>\w+)\w/
     # ^-----^-- atomic group
```

that doesn't match the string, when without the atomic group, the pattern succeeds:

```
/(\w+) \w+\w/
```

More about atomic groups: http://regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

This particularity is also described here (but only in a recursive context): http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html *(see "Recursion Depths are Atomic")*

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about "atomic by default" @Casimir

Comment: Ok... I think I get it now. Thanks. Can you also tell me if there is a way to "non-atomicize" (if that is a valid phrase) a PCRE regex?

Comment: @Wraith: unfortunately, it's not possible.